# Using testing.Benchmark does not produce any output

Tags: go

I'm using `testing.Benchmark` to manually run a couple benchmarks but the result object is always empty.

Am I missing something here?

Here's an example:

```
package main

import "testing"

func main() {

    result := testing.Benchmark(func(parentB *testing.B) {
        parentB.Run("example", func(b *testing.B) {
            for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                println("ok")
            }
        })
    })

    println(result.String())

}
```

This will print `ok` a couple times and then `0          0 ns/op` but the benchmark clearly did run something.

Comment: have you tried it with some "pure" calculations and not just printing?

Comment: not sure I understand how to do it.

Comment: well, it doesn't matter. I tried it myself and it's indeed not working, contrary to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing everything right. Doc of [`testing.Benchmark()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) says:

> Benchmark benchmarks a single function. Useful for creating custom benchmarks that do not use the "go test" command.
>
> If f calls Run, the result will be an estimate of running all its subbenchmarks that don't call Run in sequence in a single benchmark.

Looking into the implementation (Go 1.7.4):

```
func Benchmark(f func(b *B)) BenchmarkResult {
    b := &B{
        common: common{
            signal: make(chan bool),
            w:      discard{},
        },
        benchFunc: f,
        benchTime: *benchTime,
    }
    if !b.run1() {
        return BenchmarkResult{}
    }
    return b.run()
}
```

This line:

```
    if !b.run1() {
        return BenchmarkResult{}
    }
```

`b.run1()` is supposed to run your passed function once, and detect if it has sub-benchmarks. Yours has. It returns a `bool` whether more runs are needed. Inside `run1()`:

```
if b.hasSub || b.finished {
    // ...
    return true
}
```

It properly tells it has sub-benchmark, and `Benchmark()` –with noble simplicity– just returns an empty `BenchmarkResult`:

```
    if !b.run1() {
        return BenchmarkResult{}
    }
```

I do believe that either this is a bug (or rather "incomplete" feature), or doc is incorrect. I suggest to file an issue here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues

Answer (score 1):

Eddited the answer to clarify:

My guess is that you are using go run to run the test. That will not produce any result. In order to run the code exatly as it is written you need to use
go test -bench=.  and I think it should work.
The file must be named test_xxx.go   where xxx is whatever you want.

If you restucture you code a litle bit it can be run as a single function benchmark:

```
package main

import "testing"

func main() {
    myTest()
}

func myTest() {
    fn := func(b *testing.B) {
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            println("ok")
        }
    }
    result := testing.Benchmark(fn)

    println(result.String())
}
```

Comment: '`Benchmark` benchmarks a single function. Useful for creating custom benchmarks that do not use the "go test" command.'

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. To run the code exactly as it was written he need to use run -bench=.
I'll edit my original answer with how to restructure it a bit to make it test a single function.

Comment: @PeterFendrich Yes, not using sub-benchmarks works. But according to the docs, what the asker tried should also work (most likely he has many more sub-benchmark which are not included in the question for brevity), and that is what this question is about.

Comment: Yes, not using subs works, but that's not what I'm looking for.